# How to get surround sound speakers working "speaker-fill-style" with SB 5.1 VX

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card, 5.1

I have a 5.1 soundsystem connected to a "SB 5.1 vx" soundcard on Win10. It's running fine generally - when testing it through the windows sound driver options it works, I can hear sounds from ALL speakers.
But since almost nothing has 5.1 built-in - youtube, my mp3s, etc. I can't profit much of it...but at least I would like to hear music coming out of all speakers...

I was especially hoping to see a "Speaker fill" checkbox somewhere but nope...
I downloaded the newest driver [here](https://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&prodID=17510&prodName=Sound%20Blaster%205.1%20VX) but I couldn't find any options to get music coming from the 3 surround speakers. Only the two stereo ones play music from regular mp3 files.
I used the driver that windows installs automatically too but I also couldn't find anything to get the other 3 speakers working.

Creative Driver:
[image: Creative Driver]
Driver installed by Win10 automatically:
[image: Default Windows Driver]

Answer (score 0):

A tad late, but I was searching for the same option and...

https://pw999.wordpress.com/2018/02/04/speaker-fill-not-working/

...the option speaker fill seems to be eliminated from newer versions of the realtek driver. So the only option you have is to downgrade your driver to the version mentioned in the article.